# Hide ngx-popover only on mobile view

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-popover

I have a NgbPopover which works fine in desktop view and in the tablet view. But I want to hide it only in the mobile view.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add one media query in css which hides the popover on mobile view:

```
  @media screen and (max-width:576px){
    ::ng-deep .popover{ display:none; }
  }
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfkx6p)

Answer (score 0):

```
Hide popover I am using disable Popover
<button type="button" class="btn p-0 qty" placement="right" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [disablePopover]="isPopoverShow" >
------------------------------------------------------------------------

.TS
 if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
            this.isPopoverShow = true;
        }else {
            this.isPopoverShow = false;
        }
```